# Django: Fetch a true/false with extra() if a matching record exists in another table

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm, django-mysql

I have a model `Registration` with a foreign key to model `License` which has a unique CharField `key`.

For a certain set of Registrations I need to get a boolean if an `Activation` record exists with that license key.
There is however no foreignkey relation between `Activation` and `Registration`/`License`.

I can do it in python like that:

```
regis = Registration.objects.filter(...).select_related("license")

keys = regis.values_list("license__key", flat=True)
activated_keys = ActivationRecord.objects.filter(licensekey__in=keys, action="OK").values_list("licensekey", flat=True)
for r in regis:
    r._was_activated = r.free_license.key in activated_keys
```

But was thinking this should be possible with an `extra()` call. Just my sql skills are not good enough.

What I came up with was:

```
Registration.objects.filter(...).extra(
    select={"was_activated":"SELECT EXISTS(select * FROM `activation_activationrecord`, `license_license` 
where `license_license`.`license_key`=`activation_activationrecord`.`licensekey` AND `activation_activationrecord`.`action` = 'OK')"})
```

But `r.was_activated` is always `1` for any record, if activated or not.

---

**Update**: here the related part of the tables:

```
mysql> Describe activation_activationrecord;
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| licensekey      | varchar(250)  | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| action          | varchar(100)  | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+

mysql> Describe license_license;
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| license_key                | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> Describe registration_registration;
+--------------------------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                                      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| registration_id                            | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| license_id                                 | int(11)    | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+--------------------------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

---

**Update 2**: The relevant models:

```
class Registration(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(db_column="registration_id", primary_key=True)
    license = models.OneToOneField(License,
    related_name='registration',
    default=False,
    blank=False)


class License(models.Model):

    key = models.CharField(db_column="license_key", max_length= 255)


class ActivationRecord(models.Model):

    licensekey = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, db_index=True)
```

Comment: please post your tables.

Comment: @e4c5 sure, just added it to the post

Comment: is it a raw query that you want or an ORM query? For a Raw query yes, what's needed is your tables but it doesn't show the foriegn key relationships clearly. If it's an orm query what you need is the models.

Comment: @e4c5 I would prefer to go as far as possible with the ORM as long as I can avoid a huge number of queries for accessing the `was_activated` flag for each registration. I added the model info, the real code is very abstract and split over many classes so I had to sum it up to the relevant parts, hope that helps. Thank you very much for your time! :)

Comment: On a side note, I'm not in a position to change the models easily.